# How to make the Visual Studio debugger stop when a handled exception occurs in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm trying to understand why and where an exception is thrown in my C# code. The problem is that all my code is in try-catch blocks, so debugger doesn't stop when it happens. Is there a way to explicitly tell it to stop?

Comment: Hi,

Is it a web or win application??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> shortcut to bring up the exceptions dialog. There you can select any exceptions for which you'd like Visual Studio to break.

Answer (score 4):

See [How to: Break When an Exception is Thrown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d14azbfh%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) on MSDN.

> To break execution when an exception
>   is thrown
>
> (1) On the **Debug** menu, click **Exceptions**.
>
> > **Note** If the Exceptions command does not appear on the Debug menu, you can add
> >     it. For more information, see To add
> >     the Exceptions command to the Debug
> >     menu.
>
> (2)
>
> In the **Exceptions** dialog box, select **Thrown** for an entire category
>   of exceptions, for example, **Common
>   Language Runtime Exceptions**.
>
> -or-
>
> Expand the node for a category of exceptions, for example, **Common
>   Language Runtime Exceptions**, and
>   select **Thrown** for a specific exception
>   within that category.

Comment: +1. Note that you may need to disable "my code only" (tools -> options-> debugging -> my code only) if exception is thrown outside of the code that VS considers "my code".

Comment: That might be useful. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In Visual Studio, click on the Debug menu, select Exceptions, then check "Thrown" to the right of "Common Language Runtime Exceptions".

Answer (score 1):

Goto Debug, Exceptions...

You can select what exceptions you want to break on.